# Memory warning with MonoTouch 6.0.4

Tags: xamarin.ios

My app is a single view application. It also starts getting memory warnings just by navigating around between screens, sometimes with triggering the keyboard or date time picker to open.

Especially, it goes crash when I browse a view which contains **MKMapView control**. The problem occurs on real device but it works quite fine on **iOS simulator**.

I'm using **MonoTouch 6.0.4** & **XCode 4.3**.

Comment: This question does not contain any valuable information that would allow somebody to help you. Please show us code, post the stack trace of the crash. What have you tried so far? Have you investigated with Instruments or the MonoTouch Profiler where the memory is going?

Comment: It's really weird. I clean & rebuild the app and the problem has gone. Thank you for your suggestion. I will try to use Instruments an MonoTouch Profiler. I'm new to MonoTouch.